# Fluent Validation - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I'm using fluent validation in MVC 3. Is it possible  to turn off fluent validation for specific post action in controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `AttributedValidatorFactory` and you wanted to disable validation for the Index action on Home controller for POST verbs you could write a custom validator factory:

```
public class MyAttributedValidatorFactory : AttributedValidatorFactory
{
    private readonly Func<HttpContextBase> _contextAccessor;
    public MyAttributedValidatorFactory(Func<HttpContextBase> contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public override IValidator GetValidator(Type type)
    {
        var context = _contextAccessor();
        var rd = context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var action = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
        var controller = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");

        if (string.Equals("post", context.Request.HttpMethod, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals("index", action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
            string.Equals("home", controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        )
        if (type == typeof(MyViewModel))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return base.GetValidator(type);
    }
}
```

which will be used to replace the default one in your `Application_Start`:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(config =>
{
    Func<HttpContextBase> contextAccessor = 
        () => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    config.ValidatorFactory = new MyAttributedValidatorFactory(contextAccessor);
});
```

and then if you have the following action on the Home controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

FluentValidation won't kick in.

Comment: Can I somehow preserve validation errors from previous submit?

Comment: Erm what? What does *previous submit means*? HTTP is a stateless protocol. I think that you should explain what exactly are you trying to achieve. Maybe there are better ways.

Comment: I have two submit buttons on my form. When first one is clicked input should not be validated but when another one is clicked input should be validated, and if user click first one again then error message should still be shown ...

Comment: That's a pretty strange requirement. Why does the 2 buttons call the same controller action? What does the first submit button do when the action is invoked assuming there's no validation performed?

Comment: It's not the same controller action. First just add some new fields depending on what user has entered

Comment: How are you handling the different actions then? Submit buttons normally invoke the action that's specified in the `action` attribute of the containing form. Could you show some code to put your descriptions into a more realistic context?

Comment: I'm using Attributes like this : http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/26/Supporting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-ASPNET-MVC-view.aspx

Comment: OK I see. So what does the first controller action do (the one that doesn't perform validation and yet takes the same view model)?

Comment: It add additional fields depending on what user has already entered in input fields

Comment: OK, so what happens if you leave validation for that action? Why do you need to disable it in this case? You could add the fields you need based on the input of some other fields and still preserve the validation messages.

Comment: If user try to save data, and there are validations error and then user try to add additional fields with first button, validations error will be deleted...

Comment: They will not be deleted if you don't disable FluentValidation.

Comment: I can handle this with javascript but I was hoping that there is some other solution

Comment: No, you don't need javascript for that. The server can handle it. If you leave the validation, when the first button is clicked, this validation will be performed and errors added to the modelstate so that when the view is shown error messages will appear.

Comment: But if I leave validation, error messages will be shown when first button is clicked and I don't want that

Comment: Got it. Sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Hay men you have miss some important point of fluentvalidation called the Validator customization.

find here http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc

Validator customization

With FluentValidation v3 you can use the CustomizeValidatorAttribute to configure how the validator will be run. For example, if you want the validator to only run for a particular ruleset then you can specify that ruleset name by attributing the parameter that is going to be validated:

```
public ActionResult Save([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet="MyRuleset")] Customer cust) {
  // ...
}
```

this